# Is there an effective way to diff two dependencies-tree populated by `npm list`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependencies

Before the project release, we need to check which dependencies updated which may impact other pages. We can leverage `npm list` to populate the full-dependencies-tree. How to effectively perform `diff` with two different trees to find out which pages impacted by the dependency update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`npm list --json --silent` will give you a JSON object. (`--silent` is to suppress error output that will ruin your JSON)

Depending on how you want to proceed, you could use a terminal tool like `jq` and `diff` to get a diff.

You could also pull the results into a node app and use one of the many npm libraries like `json-diff` to produce a json structure representing the diff.

You can also parse `package-lock.json` instead of using `npm list`